# Add a HTML class to (each parent of) the current page

Tags: php

I have a array which holds my navigation structure (snippet 1) which I want to convert into 's (with li's and a's). The code in snippet 2 is working correctly and it creates a perfect HTML structure. The only thing I want to add now is an .active class on each item that is (a parent of) the current page.

For example, when I am on the /test/testtest page, both the li with /test and the li with /testtest (as a child of /test) should get the .active class. Oh, and `$this->page->path` returns the current path, which is `/test/testtest` in this example.

I hope it's clear like this, it's a little hard to explain.

Snippet 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /home
    [1] => /test
    [test] => Array
        (
            [0] => /test/testtest
            [testtest] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /test/testtest/3deep
                )

            [1] => /test/testtest2
        )

    [2] => /test2
    [3] => /nieuws
)
```

Snippet 2:

```
private function generateStructure($array) {
    foreach ( $array as $element ) {
        if ( is_array($element) ) {
            ?>
            <ul>
                <?= $this->generateStructure($element) ?>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <?php
        } else {
            $classArray = array();
            $close = (is_array(next($array))) ? false : true;

            // Active class
            if ( $this->pages[$element]["path"] == $this->page->path ) array_push($classArray, "active");

            $classes = "";
            if ( !empty($classArray) ) {
                $classes = 'class="';
                foreach ( $classArray as $class ) {
                    $classes .= $class . " ";
                }

                $classes = trim($classes) . '"';
            }

            ?>
            <li <?= $classes ?>><a href="/ocms-dev<?= $this->pages[$element]["path"] ?>"><?= $this->pages[$element]["titleNav"] ?></a>
            <?php

            // Only close it when the current element has no subnav
            if ( $close ) echo "</li>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if the if ( $this->pages[$element]["path"] == $this->page->path ) is resulting true at all? I'd be tempted to echo the value of $this->pages[$element]["path"] to confirm what that is comparing to $this->page->path.

Comment: It returns true only for the current page, so `/test/testtest == /test/testtest`. But I need it to work on its parents too...

Comment: Ah I see, well one way to do that is to pass a flag into the recursive function that remembers if the flag has previously been set by that comparison, then if either the comparison or the flag is true then set the class.

Comment: Actually the way round it is you'll need to get the recursive function to return a flag if any of it's children are set as active.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've de-classed it a bit to try stuff out here and I can get it to work like this:-

```
function generateStructure($array) {
    foreach ( $array as $element ) {
        if ( is_array($element) ) {
        ?>
        <ul>
            <?PHP  generateStructure($element) ?>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <?php
    } else {
        $classArray = array();
        $close = (is_array(next($array))) ? false : true;

        // Active class
        if ( $element == '/test/testtest' ){ 
            array_push($classArray, "active");
            echo ("match found");
        }

        $classes = "";
        if ( !empty($classArray) ) {
            $classes = 'class="';
            foreach ( $classArray as $class ) {
                $classes .= $class . " ";
            }

            $classes = trim($classes) . '"';
        }

        ?>
        <li <?PHP echo $classes ?>><a href="/ocms-dev<?PHP echo $element ?>"><?PHP echo $element ?></a>
        <?php

        // Only close it when the current element has no subnav
        if ( $close ) echo "</li>";
    }
}
}
?>
```

I think it's mainly down to me switching $this->pages[$element]["path"] with $element in the if comparison ... that looks to be the problem.

Comment: No, I don't think so... I need every li to have the .active class. Now, still only one li will get the .active class. I need it to return 'match found' (from your example) on every element. So on both `/test` and `/test/testtest`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found a solution to my problem.

I decided to introduce a `level` variable (`$this->level`), which I then use to compare the nth child of an array with the exploded parts of both URLs (current element in loop & current page).